# Create a new txt file using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How do I create an empty `.txt` file in the location `C:\my files\2010` using VB.NET?

Comment: This code was really useful. Thanks ---
RRPV

Answer (score 58):

Here is a single line that will create (or [overwrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) the file:

```
File.Create("C:\my files\2010\SomeFileName.txt").Dispose()
```

Note: calling Dispose() ensures that the reference to the file is closed.

Comment: yeah I am a newbie to this when I use the example Im prompted with the error Name 'File' is not declared I know how to declare string bat not name?

Comment: @Schenz: I know, lol, that's why i put in the sample. I imagined myself from ways back thinking: "Where the heck did filename come from?"

Comment: @sam: you need to import `File`, like this: `Imports System` (line break) `Imports System.IO`

Comment: add Imports System.IO to the top of the class, or change example to System.IO.File.Create("C:\my files\2010\SomeFileName.txt").Dispose()

Comment: @Sam: You need to add an import to the top of your file like this: Imports System.IO

Answer (score 26):

You also might want to check if the file already exists to avoid replacing the file by accident (unless that is the idea of course:

```
Dim filepath as String = "C:\my files\2010\SomeFileName.txt"
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
   System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was able to create the file, but it would become locked. And your code helped me get past the road bump. Thank you Geoffrey. Wayne

Answer (score 5):

You can try writing into the Documents folder. Here is a "debug" function I did for the debugging needs of my project:

```
Private Sub writeDebug(ByVal x As String)
    Dim path As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = path & "\mydebug.txt"
    MsgBox(FILE_NAME)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = False Then
        System.IO.File.Create(FILE_NAME).Dispose()
    End If
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
    objWriter.WriteLine(x)
    objWriter.Close()
End Sub
```

There are more standard folders you can access through the "SpecialFolder" object.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this

```
FileOpen(1, "C:\my files\2010\SomeFileName.txt", OpenMode.Output)
FileClose(1)
```

This opens the file replaces whatever is in it and closes the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
open C:\myfile.txt for append as #1
write #1, text1.text, text2.text
close()
```

This is the code I use in [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline). It helps me to create a txt file on my drive, write two pieces of data into it, and then close the file... Give it a try...